# Android, problem in stopping animation

Tags: android, animation

In my android project I have an image that i want to rotate it and create animation for long time. 
I can run program and it works fine. but I don't know how can I stop it. if you know please tell me.

Thanks

This is my code, I have a menu with two items, When I click on Start item, startAnimation function runs and when I click on Stop item, stopAnimation runs.:

```
public class Hypnagogic extends Activity 
{
    ImageView imView;
    Animation an;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imView);
    }

    private void startAnimation()
    {
        an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.spin);
        imView.startAnimation(an);
    }

    private void stopAnimation()
    {
        ;//there is no any stop function!
    }
}
```

also, in res/anim I put spin.xml that is my animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<set>
    <rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-18000"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="50000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I see. Okay, try the [`clearAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation%28%29) method associated with the `View` class. You can call it directly on your `ImageView`, I'm almost certain this should work for your case:

```
imView.clearAnimation();
```

What have you tried? [`AnimationDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) has a `stop()` method. You need to post how you're creating/starting the animation.

Comment: Thanks dear kcoppock, I edited my question, please look at that. Thanks